# Vlookup with multiple ranges in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm looking to validate 2 numbers with conditional formatting.

I need to resolve how to vlookup "x" value within at least 3 different ranges in a different sheet (Validation) but on the same spreadsheet.

I came out with this but it not working as intended.

May you please provide me a workaround or another solution?

```
VLOOKUP(F5,INDIRECT("{INDIRECT("Validation!B17:Q19"); INDIRECT("Validation!B54:Q56");INDIRECT("Validation!B91:Q93")}"),2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you plan to use it as a conditional formatting formula, here's one workaround that you may use.

1st, Create a `Helper` sheet which will contain the combined range of data that you will use in your `vlookup()`. You can just hide your `Helper` sheet if you want.

[image]

2nd, Use `indirect()` using the range in your `Helper` sheet.

**Sample Conditional Formatting Formula:**

```
=D1=Vlookup($A$1,Indirect("Helper!A1:B"),2,false)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if the current answer doesn't resolve your issue. Please provide a sample sheet to be able to reproduce and validate the solution that will be provided. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: I've tried the suggested formula but I get "Invalid formula" in the conditional formatting window. I have added a screenshot too.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just realized that you needed a formula for your conditional formatting that is why you are using an `indirect()`. I updated the answer and see if this will fit your preference. Note that I locked the vlookup search key in my example

Comment: Thats a great solution! I'll tried in a sec. Just wondering, is there any way to indirect 3 ranges? Like in my first question?

Comment: You need to use this formula in your helper sheet `={Validation!B17:Q19; Validation!B54:Q56;Validation!B91:Q93}`  to merge multiple ranges. There is no limit in merging ranges, as long as they have the same column count and separated with `;` in `{}`